# How to delete text from gradient Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a gradient, somewhat glossy one which I cannot just repeat. There is some text on it. Is there any tool in PS to remove this text?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is not on a layer by itself, then **no** you can't automatically remove the text.

However, you can probably copy portions of the gradient and cover the text.

Comment: Pity, that there is no instrument for this... Copy solution is obvious answer, but I cannot use it cause gradient is somewhat complicated

Comment: How is a gradient complicated? Can you post an image for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Smart Delete tool. (aka Content-Aware Fill)

It's not perfect, but it at least tries to stitch together the borders and give you a starting point for repair work.